# update to database from array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

as part of a script i am creating to update stock figures from a file sent from my supplier i am stuck at the sql code on how to update it into database this is my code so far:

```
 // Get the pricelist into an array.
$lines = file($filename);

// Loop through our array
$stock=array("Y"=> "60", "N"=> "0", "C"=> "1");

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<BR>\n";

    $column = explode ( '"~"', $line ); // use the "~" as explode char
    echo $column[0] . " sku <BR>";
    echo $stock[$column[1]] . " stock <BR>"; //match short code to full text
    // etc


      // Connect to Local Database



// update data in mysql database

$sql="UPDATE oc_products Where sku='".$column[0] ."', quantity='".$stock[$column[1]]."' WHERE '[$column[0]'. ='".$column[0]."'";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey its run from a PHP page and MySql sorry should have put that in to start with

Comment: `"UPDATE oc_products Where`??? `"UPDATE oc_products SET` And yes, your code is vulnerable to sql injection